# Is there a built in sklearn cross validation function for only validating against higher indices?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I'd like to use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), but with the condition that the lowest index of the data in the validation set be greater than the largest in the training set. The reason being that the data is in time, and future data gives unfair insight that would inflate the score. There's some [discussion](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/cross_validation.html#a-note-on-shuffling) on this:

> If the data ordering is not arbitrary (e.g. samples with the same class label are contiguous), shuffling it first may be essential to get a meaningful cross- validation result. However, the opposite may be true if the samples are not independently and identically distributed. For example, if samples correspond to news articles, and are ordered by their time of publication, then shuffling the data will likely lead to a model that is overfit and an inflated validation score: it will be tested on samples that are artificially similar (close in time) to training samples.

but it's not clear to me whether any of the splitting methods listed can accomplish what i'm looking for. It seems to be the case that I can define an itterable of indices and pass that into cv, but in that case it's not clear how many I should define (does it always use all of them? do different tests get different indices?)

Comment: Maybe you can use TimeSeriesSplit in the cv argument of GridSearchCV. It is well documented here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

Comment: @Y.P This was exactly it, thanks.